# sharedRepository wrong group

Tags: git, permissions, repository

I use a bare repository where multiple devs can push.

As suggested, I used `sharedRepository = true` to tell git to give a group of users the permission to push.

When I want to add pushers, I simply add them the required group as secondary group (`sudo adduser the_pusher the_required_group`)

When devs push, I see the files created in `objects` directory created with the good permission but not the good group.

Example:

```
$ ls -l repository/objects
...
drwxrwsr-x 2 pusher1 pusher1 4096 janv.  7 14:13 fa
drwxrwsr-x 2 pusher1 pusher1 4096 déc.  26 15:29 fc
drwxrwsr-x 2 pusher1 pusher1 4096 déc.  11 12:41 fd
...
```

As you can see, the attached group is the primary group of `pusher1`

How can I make git to attach these objects to `the_required_group` instead ?

---

**Update**

I use git over ssh.
Each dev have his own ssh account.

Comment: what protocol? git or ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My team has fixed this by setting the `s` option on all directories in the repository with `chmod`  To do this `chown` and `chgrp` the files and directories to the correct user/group then `chmod g+s` everything in the repository.

The `+s` causes new files to have the group of their parent directory.  Taken from `man 2 chown`

> - If the file system is mounted with  -o nogrpid  and  the  set-group-ID  bit  is
>      enabled  on the parent directory, then the group of a new file is made the same
>      as that of the parent directory.

See also, `man chmod` and `man 2 chmod`

Comment: That's a cool solution. I'll give it a try. Couldn't we set it only on `objects` ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I think you would at least also need to do `refs` and probably `info`.  `packed-refs` is a file in the root of `$GIT_DIR` that I think might be modified periodically by pushes but I'm not sure.  If it is this would require the `$GIT_DIR` to have the option set.