# Git keeps removing group write permissions

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

I have a git repository that I am sharing with several developers. We do regular git pulls and pushes with it. Unfortunately, every time I do a git pull the changed files lose the group write permission. How do I stop git from doing this?

I am running this on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The config on the shared repo looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        sharedRepository = group
```

I also ran the following commands on it in an attempt to fix it

```
find repo.git -type d -exec chmod g+rws {} +
sudo chmod -R g+rw repo.git/objects
```

No matter what I end up with folders with 755 and files with 644 when I want 775 and 664 respectively.

Comment: I've had similar issues that were solved by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306768/file-permission-issues-with-sharing-a-git-remote-repository

Comment: I tried that, the group write permissions kept going away. That's why I asked this question separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this on a git hook with something like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# .git/hooks/post-merge

sudo chmod -R g+rw *
```

it is called after every git pull, and file (.git/hooks/post-merge) must be executable

Comment: imho, not a great answer as `sudo` is not available for many people.

Comment: you can remove `sudo` if you have rights to do the `chmod`

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `core.sharedRepository=group` or `core.sharedRepository=0664` setting.

See e.g. http://criticallog.thornet.net/2010/01/07/sharing-your-git-repository/

Comment: I'll have to try this.

Comment: I must admit that I wrote this while setting it up and it's not working for me *blush*. I wonder if I set it up correctly since it seems to be working for the link author

Comment: When using `git init --shared` it adds the config option `core.sharedrepository = 1` which is presumably the same as `true` or `group`. I'm beginning to think this applies only to the repository but not to the working files, since it also adds `receive.denyNonFastForwards`.

Answer (score 0):

The users in question also need to have their umask set to 002.